# Set a timer for the visibility of a button

Tags: java, android-studio, button, timer, visibility

This is purely theoretical put let's say once I put a timer for a button to appear only 84600 second later (like 24h), will it the count down continue after the app is shut down ?

Can the user close the app and then come back the next day and find the button after the countdown is done ?

Or is there a better way to make it happen ? Like to allow the user to see it only after 24h ?

Comment: Calculate the actual time it should show, and then use that value as it will always be right, whether or not you close it.

Comment: @trilogy Thank you fro you answer. Where can I put that ? inside the onClick of the button ?

Comment: Well, I thought you don't want it to show until the time has passed? You can check onClick if the right time has passed I suppose, then do the action if it has, but show an warning/error if it hasn't...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use **ScheduledExecutorService** to create such a timer. Then on every tick, you can open the app if you want, and show the button, or just show the button if the user open the app.
documentation is available [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService).